# Listbox rows are different each time when scroll

Tags: c#, silverlight, listbox, windows-phone-8.1

I have listbox control with custom data template. I get the collection from webservice and bind that collection to listbox. When i scroll the list box top to bottom my listbox rows are changed and text are concatenate.

Please see the below images 
This is my first screen 
[image]

when scroll top to bottom once again

[image]
please compare two images my rows are changed

```
 <Grid Margin="30,20,0,20" x:Name="MeGrid" Loaded="MeGrid_Loaded" Visibility="{Binding Path=_isMyMessage, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
                        <StackPanel >
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="#00c0d4" Margin="0,0,100,0" Text="{Binding Path=CreatedDate, Converter={StaticResource TimeSinceConverter}}" />
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                                <Grid Background="#ffffff" Height="auto" Width="auto" MaxWidth="300" MinWidth="50">
                                    <StackPanel Background="White">
                                        <RichTextBox Name="MeRich" Background="White" MaxHeight="600" Foreground="Red" 
                                                     FontFamily="Segoe UI" Margin="10,0,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                                     TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="auto" 
                                                     Width="auto" MinWidth="50"
                                                     MaxWidth="300"
                                                     local:Properties.Html="{Binding Path=MessageText}">
                                        </RichTextBox>

                                        <readMore:Readmore Source="{Binding Path=MessageText}" Visibility="{Binding ActualHeight, 
                                            ElementName=MeRich, Converter={StaticResource ReadMoreVisibilityConverter}}" ></readMore:Readmore>
                                        <!--<TextBlock Margin="10,0,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="auto" Width="auto" MinWidth="50" MaxWidth="300" Text="{Binding Path=MessageText}"

                                                   />-->
                                        <ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AttachmentList}">
                                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <Grid Margin="0,5,0,5">
                                                        <Button Click="Image_Download" Loaded="Button_Loaded" Tag="{Binding .}" Width="80" Height="80" >
                                                            <Button.Template>
                                                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                                                    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                                                                        <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                                                                    </Border>
                                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                                            </Button.Template>
                                                            <Image Source="/Resources/Drawable/c_image.png"  Tag="{Binding .}" />
                                                        </Button>
                                                        <ProgressBar VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsIndeterminate="true" Visibility="Collapsed" Style="{StaticResource CustomIndeterminateProgressBar}" />
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        </ListBox>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Grid>
                                <Rectangle Margin="20,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50" Width="80" Height="80">
                                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Path=UserPictureURL}"/>
                                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                                </Rectangle>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
```

Comment: Please post your code so we can start helping you.

Comment: @apollo i have added my code. could you please help and resolve my problem

Comment: Is the above Grid a template for your ListBox Item Template?

Comment: @M.Tovbin yes that is list template

Comment: Can you post the code that binds data to the ListBox